# Swap columns with rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, transpose

I got task to do with quite big frame in pandas. I have downloaded data from climate institution from Poland. I need to extract temperature from couple meteo stations. After some preprocessing in excell and pandas my data is grouped into one DataFrame - code below e.g:

```
df2= pd.read_excel('./Temperature.xlsx',usecols=['Station name','Year','Month','Day','Deaily mean temperature'])
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime({'year':df2['Year'],'month':df2['Month'],'day':df2['Day']})
StationGroup = df2.groupby(by='Station name')
```

Grouping stations into seperate dataframes

```
Station1=df2.loc[StationGroup.groups['GOLENIÓW']]
Station2=df2.loc[StationGroup.groups['CHRZASTOWO']]
Station3=df2.loc[StationGroup.groups['GDAŃSK-RĘBIECHOWO']]
```

And then i have concated those stations into one df which is presented in table below:

```
Stacje=pd.concat(ListaStacji).set_index('Data')
```

| **Date** | **Station Name** | **Daily mean temperature** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-05-01 | Station1 | -0.5 |
| 2013-05-02 | Station1 | -1 |
| 2013-05-03 | Station1 | -0.7 |
| * | * |  |
| 2013-05-01 | Station2 | -2.5 |
| 2013-05-02 | Station2 | -1.8 |
| 2013-05-03 | Station2 | -0.3 |
| * | * |  |
| 2013-05-01 | Station1 | -0.3 |
| 2013-05-02 | Station1 | 0.5 |
| 2013-05-03 | Station1 | 0.2 |

I want to have my data in one dataframe but in seperate columns, then i could work on this data e.g:

| **Date** | **Station1** | **Station2** | **Station3** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-05-01 | -0.5 | -2.5 | 0.3 |
| 2013-05-02 | -1 | -1.8 | 0.5 |
| 2013-05-03 | -0.7 | -0.3 | 0.2 |

Thank for any informations and advices

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, you can use Pandas [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to get the desired output:

```
df.pivot(columns="Station Name", values=["Daily mean temperature"], index="Date")["Daily mean temperature"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first groupby stations and dates and then use `Stacje.T` it will transpose your data frame (change columns with rows)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers guys. I followed qualitaetsmuell suggestion and i achive what i want. At the beginning i`ve got table like this :
[FirstVersionOfDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQWjz.png)

```
df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns=['Station name'],values='Daily mean temperature'
```

so my table is look like i want
[EndVersionOfDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZfW9.png)